# What is the largest possible intersection of the three polygons?

Tags: geometry

> A hexagon, triangle, and square all with equal side lengths of $5$ are drawn. What is the largest possible intersection of the three polygons?

This question seems hard to determine the answer to because how can I determine where and when the maximal intersection occurs?

Comment: Is the hexagon assumed regular?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The square fits inside the hexagon, and the triangle fits inside the square. So the largest possible intersection is the triangle itself.

Comment: Prove that the triangle fits inside the square.

Comment: Place the triangle so that one of its sides coincides with a side of the square. The other vertex is then inside the square.

Comment: Ah, good point.

Comment: What if the question instead said, "A hexagon, triangle, and square all with equal side lengths of $6,5$ and $4$ are drawn, respectively. What is the largest possible intersection of the three polygons?"

Comment: I'm not sure in that case. But the square still fits inside the hexagon, so the problem is the same as if you only had a triangle and a square. It might still be the case that the triangle fits inside the square, but it would take a calculation.

Comment: No, the triangle wouldn't fit inside the square.

Comment: Yes, so the question is more interesting in this case right?

Answer (score 0):

The maximum area is the area of the triangle which is (5/4) times the square root of 3 because the maximum intersection of all three is the entire triangle.

The reason is because of two simple facts.
(1) Given any square of side=s (in this case s=5), it is possible to inscribe an equilateral triangle of side s in the square:  Just let one side of the square be one side of the triangle, so two vertices of the triangle are the same as two vertices of the square.  The third vertex of the triangle is in the interior of the square because the angles of the triangle (all 60 degrees) are less than the angles of the square (90), and the total length or height or altitude of the triangle to the common side is s times sq. rt of 3 divided by 2, which is less than s.  Since the triangle lies completely inside the square (including boundary), the intersection of these two is the full triangle itself.

(2)  Similarly, the maximum possible intersection of a square (or other regular plane figure) with a hexagon (or other regular plane figure that has more sides), will be the square (the plane figure with the fewer number of sides).  Again the reason is that we can make one side of the square (or the first regular figure) correspond to one side of the hexagon (second regular figure) since all sides are length s.  Since the hexagon (or 2nd figure) has 120 degree angles which is larger the 90 degrees in the angles of the square (or first regular figure), it is possible to draw lines perpendicular to the common side that extend into the interior of the hexagon (or fig. 2).  Since the distance across the hexagon (or figure 2) is greater than s, the remaining vertices of the square (fig. 1) lie totally inside the hexagon (fig. 2).  Hence their intersection is the square, and the intersection of all 3 is the triangle.

In general a regular figure in a plane is polygon of n sides (for any number n) where all the lengths of the sides are equal, and all the angles are equal.

If n>m and a regular n-gon of side=s and a regular m-gon of side = s, then it is always possible to construct the m-gon inside the n-gon because the n-gon has bigger angles and a bigger diameter.

For notation consider n1, n2, ni, etc. to mean n-sub-1, n-sub-2, n-sub-i:

Thus, if one were to construct k regular n-gons all of side length = s, but each n-gon has a different number of sides, say n1, n2, n3,...nk, in increasing order, then it is possible to construct each ni (for i from 1 to k-1 ) in any nj whose subscript j > i, but not vice versa.

As a result the largest possible intersection is the smallest of the n-gons, namely, the n1-gon.

Comment: I am assuming all figures are regular.  The above may not be true if they are not all regular, but in that case the area of any n-gon (whose sides are equal but not all angles are =) would be less than the area of a regular n-gon, so using regular n-gons maximizes the area.

Comment: If a square of side 5 fits inside a hexagon of side 5, a fortiori it fits in side a hexagon of side 6.  Similarly if a triangle of  side 5 fits inside a square of side 5, then certainly a smaller tirangle (one whose side is only 4) will also fit, so the answer remains that it the area of the triangle which is sq. rt. of 3.